grouping products by quarters with Partition BY 
here is my sql query on STANDARD Oracle SH schema to get information about all "Photo" products from "Asia" for year 2000 divided by quarters:
SELECT
  PROD_NAME AS PROD_NAME,
  Q1,
  Q2,
  Q3,
  Q4
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      p.PROD_NAME,
      p.PROD_SUBCATEGORY,
      SUM(SUM( s.AMOUNT_SOLD)) Over (Partition BY p.PROD_NAME) AS Q1,
      SUM(SUM(s.AMOUNT_SOLD)) Over (Partition BY p.PROD_NAME) AS Q2,
      SUM(SUM(s.AMOUNT_SOLD)) Over (Partition BY p.PROD_NAME) AS Q3,
      SUM(SUM(s.AMOUNT_SOLD)) Over (Partition BY p.PROD_NAME) AS Q4
    FROM
      sales s,
      customers c,
      countries co,
      products p,
      times t
    WHERE
      s.CUST_ID      = c.CUST_ID
    AND c.COUNTRY_ID = co.COUNTRY_ID
    AND s.PROD_ID    = p.PROD_ID
    AND s.TIME_ID    = t.TIME_ID
    AND
      (
        t.CALENDAR_YEAR             = '2000'
      AND co.COUNTRY_REGION         = 'Asia'
      AND p.PROD_CATEGORY           = 'Photo'
      AND t.CALENDAR_QUARTER_NUMBER = 1
      )
    GROUP BY
      p.PROD_NAME,
      p.PROD_SUBCATEGORY
    ORDER BY
      p.PROD_NAME,
      p.PROD_SUBCATEGORY
  )
WHERE
  Q1 > 1;

The problem is that by using t.CALENDAR_QUARTER_NUMBER = 1 i get data only for the first quarter. 
Here is the result i need to get:

How can i improve it? Thank you.

please post some sample data and the table structures. Even better create a SQL Fiddle

The SUM(SUM()) looks strange to me.  I can't swear that Oracle does not support it.  However, I usually do the calculations for something like Q1-Q4 in a subquery with the group by, and then do the analytic function at a higher level.
The following query also fixes your join syntax and moves the ORDER BY to the outermost level:
SELECT PROD_NAME AS PROD_NAME, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4
FROM (select Prod_name, Prod_Subcategory,
             SUM(q1) over (PARTITION by prod_name) as Q1,
             SUM(q2) over (PARTITION by prod_name) as Q2,
             SUM(q3) over (PARTITION by prod_name) as Q3,
             SUM(q4) over (PARTITION by prod_name) as Q4
      from (SELECT p.PROD_NAME, p.PROD_SUBCATEGORY,
                   SUM(case when CALENDAR_QUARTER_NUMBER = 1 then s.Amount_Sold else 0 end) as Q1,
                   SUM(case when CALENDAR_QUARTER_NUMBER = 2 then s.Amount_Sold else 0 end) as Q2,
                   SUM(case when CALENDAR_QUARTER_NUMBER = 3 then s.Amount_Sold else 0 end) as Q3,
                   SUM(case when CALENDAR_QUARTER_NUMBER = 4 then s.Amount_Sold else 0 end) as Q4,
                   SUM(SUM( s.AMOUNT_SOLD)) Over (Partition BY p.PROD_NAME) AS Q1,
                   SUM(SUM(s.AMOUNT_SOLD)) Over (Partition BY p.PROD_NAME) AS Q2,
                   SUM(SUM(s.AMOUNT_SOLD)) Over (Partition BY p.PROD_NAME) AS Q3,
                   SUM(SUM(s.AMOUNT_SOLD)) Over (Partition BY p.PROD_NAME) AS Q4
             FROM sales s join
                  customers c
                  on s.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID join
                  countries co
                  on c.COUNTRY_ID = co.COUNTRY_ID join
                  products p
                  on s.PROD_ID = p.PROD_ID join
                  times t
                  on s.TIME_ID    = t.TIME_ID
             WHERE t.CALENDAR_YEAR = '2000' and
                   co.COUNTRY_REGION = 'Asia' and
                   p.PROD_CATEGORY = 'Photo'
            GROUP BY p.PROD_NAME, p.PROD_SUBCATEGORY
           ) t
      ) t
where Q1 > 1
ORDER BY PROD_NAME, PROD_SUBCATEGORY

I note that you are ordering by PROD_SUBCATEGORY, but not including it in the final results.  This looks strange.  If there is only one subcategory, then you can greatly simplify the query.  Just use the subquery in the middle, and remove prod_subcategory from the GROUP BY and SELECT clauses.

Thank you so much, appreciate it.
